# what's a good way to get file size?

Tags: c#, .net

In our customized C# logging system, we use `streamWriter = File.CreateText(fileNameStr);` to create a file and open a stream for write.

Now we want to monitor the file size to see if it reach the max required size. What I did is the following:

1. create a FileInfo object for about file: `currFileInfo = new FileInfo(fileNameStr);`
2. get file size after each write: `curFileInfo.Refresh(); fileSize = curFileInfo.Length;`
3. compare the file size with max file size, if bigger, close the current one and create a new file.

I have print out to see how long it will take to refresh the FileInfo, many times it will take about 15msec.

So I am thinking there may be a better way to do this. what's your suggestion?

Comment: Most of the common logging frameworks support this functionality out the box, preferable to trying to write it yourself IMO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
streamWriter.BaseStream.Position;
```

This should contain the current position of the stream and if you're using it for appending only, this should contain the correct file size.

Answer (score 1):

```
FileSystemWatcher fsw=new FileSystemWatcher(filePath);
fsw.NotifyFilter=NotifyFilters.Size;
fsw.Filter="fileName";
fsw.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(YourHandler); 
fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = True;
```

Comment: +1 Good idea, but you should mention what this code does and how. It's a different from 5yrs' approach in that it creates a monitor which will fire events. So the approach here is event driven as opposed to a polling system that the OP started with.